# undefined reference EVP_sha1 , HMAC, Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, qt, undefined, qmake, hmac

i´ve got a problem with the Error above. 
In m Code is the HMAC implemented.
i tried solving the problem with this link: [Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=131726)

But it just doesnt work so i hope you can help me. im really stuck with this and played with the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS but just got no positiv solution.

here is the .pro:

```
QT       += core gui webkit network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = csui
TEMPLATE = app




#QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -lssl -lcrypto
#QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -lcrypto



target.path = /home/msw

INSTALLS += target

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
    qcolpushbutton.cpp \
    librfid/mifare.cpp \
    librfid/list.cpp \
    librfid/brp.cpp \
    qrfid.cpp \
    qscaledlabel.cpp \
    statelogic.cpp \
    qcsnp.cpp \
    qchargepoint.cpp \
    qi2cnode.cpp \
    libhotp-tan.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    qcolpushbutton.h \
    debug.h \
    config.h \
    librfid/mifare.h \
    librfid/list.h \
    librfid/brp.h \
    qrfid.h \
    qscaledlabel.h \
    statelogic.h \
    qcsnp.h \
    qchargepoint.h \
    qi2cnode.h \
    libhotp-tan.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    res/res.qrc
```

and the links from the Makefile

```
CFLAGS        = -pipe -isystem /home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/include -isystem /home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/include -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -isystem /home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/include -isystem /home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/include -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
```

```css
13:45:58: Führe Schritte für Projekt csui aus...
13:45:59: Starte "/opt/qt-4.8.3e-armhf/sysroot-cross/bin/qmake" '/home/msw/Arbeitsfläche/Experimentelles Programm/csui.pro' -r -spec /opt/qt-4.8.3e-armhf/sysroot-target/usr/mkspecs/qws/linux-ptx-g++
13:45:59: Der Prozess "/opt/qt-4.8.3e-armhf/sysroot-cross/bin/qmake" wurde normal beendet.
13:45:59: Starte "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Entering directory `/home/msw/Arbeitsfläche/Experimentelles Programm'
arm-1136jfs-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/lib -L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link -Wl,/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/lib -Wl,-rpath-link -Wl,/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/lib -Wl,-O1 -o csui main.o mainwindow.o qcolpushbutton.o mifare.o list.o brp.o qrfid.o qscaledlabel.o statelogic.o qcsnp.o qchargepoint.o qi2cnode.o libhotp-tan.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_qcolpushbutton.o moc_qrfid.o moc_qscaledlabel.o moc_statelogic.o moc_qcsnp.o moc_qchargepoint.o moc_qi2cnode.o qrc_res.o    -L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/lib -L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/lib -lQtWebKit -lQtGui -L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/lib -L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/lib -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lpthread 
make: Leaving directory `/home/msw/Arbeitsfläche/Experimentelles Programm'
libhotp-tan.o: In function `hotpa(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, char*, unsigned int, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)':
libhotp-tan.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
libhotp-tan.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `HMAC'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [csui] Error 1
13:46:01: Der Prozess "/usr/bin/make" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 2 beendet.
Fehler beim Erstellen/Deployment des Projekts csui(Ziel: Embedded Linux)
Bei der Ausführung von Schritt 'Make'
```

THANKS!!

Comment: To get help with a failing linkage you need to post at least the failing
linker command line and the ensuing errors, verbatim.

Comment: i inserted the pro and some parts of the makefile hope it will help. Thanks!

Comment: The failing linker commandline is the `g++\gcc` commandline that fails
when executed and is followed by the linkage error messages. It
isn't in the makefile. You see will see these in the build output when the build fails. Copy the failing commandline and error messages from the build output and paste them in the body of your question, *indented 4 spaces*.

Comment: do you mean this?...thanks really much btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linkage command is:

```
arm-1136jfs-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \ 
-L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/lib \ 
-L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/lib \ 
-Wl,-rpath-link \
-Wl,/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/lib \ 
-Wl,-rpath-link \
-Wl,/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/lib \ 
-Wl,-O1 \
-o csui main.o mainwindow.o qcolpushbutton.o mifare.o list.o brp.o qrfid.o \
qscaledlabel.o statelogic.o qcsnp.o qchargepoint.o qi2cnode.o libhotp-tan.o \ 
moc_mainwindow.o moc_qcolpushbutton.o moc_qrfid.o moc_qscaledlabel.o moc_statelogic.o \
moc_qcsnp.o moc_qchargepoint.o moc_qi2cnode.o qrc_res.o \    
-L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/lib \
-L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/lib \ 
-lQtWebKit \
-lQtGui \
-L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/usr/lib \
-L/home/msw/crossdev/OSELAS.BSP-RaspberryPi/platform-RaspberryPi/sysroot-target/lib \
-lQtNetwork \
-lQtCore \
-lpthread
```

(There's a lot of redundant repetition there)

The undefined symbols `EVP_sha1` and `HMAC` are defined in `libcrypto`, for which
you need also to link `libssl`, but `-lssl -lcrypto`
are not among the library options you are passing to the linker. You need to add them.

I'm not familiar with QMake but I believe library options should be defined in 
[`LIBS`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) If you generate a linker
commandline with `-lssl -lcrypto` following `-lQtCore` you should be all right.

I notice that `-lssl -lcrypto` appears in the commented-out setting:

```
#QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -lssl -lcrypto
```

That wouldn't have worked, since it's setting options for the C Compiler in
release mode, not the linker. Likewise `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`, which you say you
tinkered with, sets options for the C++ compiler, not the linker.

Comment: In all of that you spotted the missing libraries, hats off to you.